# Using augtool, how do you add an SSH subsystem, or update a subsystem if already present?

Tags: sshd

Given an sshd_config file that contains the following config:

```
Subsystem   sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
Subsystem   fooftp /usr/lib/openssh/fooftp-server
Subsystem   barftp /usr/lib/openssh/barftp-server
```

How would `augtool` a) add an entry for snmp if it does not exist; and b) update an existing entry for `augtool` if it already exists.

I see that existing entries can be accessed like this:

```
/files/etc/ssh/sshd_config/Subsystem[1]/sftp
/files/etc/ssh/sshd_config/Subsystem[2]/fooftp
/files/etc/ssh/sshd_config/Subsystem[3]/barftp
```

and a new entry can be added like this:

```
/files/etc/ssh/sshd_config/Subsystem[4]/bazftp
```

However 4 above is a magic number, and so not useful.

Does `augtool` have a syntax that can help?

An example of a possible existing config looks like this:

```
augtool> print /files/etc/ssh/sshd_config/Subsystem
/files/etc/ssh/sshd_config/Subsystem[1]
/files/etc/ssh/sshd_config/Subsystem[1]/sftp = "/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server"
/files/etc/ssh/sshd_config/Subsystem[2]
/files/etc/ssh/sshd_config/Subsystem[2]/snmp = "/usr/bin/sshtosnmp /var/lib/net-snmp/sshdomainsocket"
```

https://github.com/hercules-team/augeas/pull/706 added in v1.13.0 of augeas would suggest the + operator could help, however it is not clear how to match option 2 above.

Note: use another tool is not an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

To idempotently create an entry if it doesn't exist / update an entry if it already does, do the following:

```
augtool> set /files/etc/ssh/sshd_config/Subsystem[foo]/foo 'something new'
augtool> print /files/etc/ssh/sshd_config/Subsystem
/files/etc/ssh/sshd_config/Subsystem[1]
/files/etc/ssh/sshd_config/Subsystem[1]/sftp = "/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server"
/files/etc/ssh/sshd_config/Subsystem[2]
/files/etc/ssh/sshd_config/Subsystem[2]/snmp = "/usr/bin/sshtosnmp /var/lib/net-snmp/sshdomainsocket"
/files/etc/ssh/sshd_config/Subsystem[3]
/files/etc/ssh/sshd_config/Subsystem[3]/foo = "something new"
augtool>
```

The syntax `Subsystem[foo]` will select the entry with the index 'foo', creating it if it does not exist, and then we assign a value to this new node with `Subsystem[foo]/foo 'something new'`.

If the node 'foo' already exists, it will be updated.

To undo what's been done, remove the node like this:

```
augtool> rm /files/etc/ssh/sshd_config/Subsystem/foo
```

Source: https://github.com/hercules-team/augeas/issues/68#issuecomment-1282915936